Yea rather than yay is used to describe height or size if you are a Caulkhead. (FYI A Caulkhead is a native of the Isle of Wight)
Some spellings are regional & dialectic. As in yea v.yay when describing approximate height or size. ie: "I saw a gert mallyshag on my path; it was yea long" (using hands to describe the length). Discuss! : )

We use "yea long" here in the US.  (Nowhere near the Isle of Wight.)

Yay is usually a cheer: Yay! Is that your question? Yea can mean yes, or like that, or even in the original Psalm "Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death."

@YosefBaskin - the first time (around 5 years ago, UK, Bristol) I heard this way of accompanying hand indications of a dimension was from someone born and bred in Shropshire (a Sikh lady from Telford, my boss in an office) and I would have to guess how to spell it. I just asked my wife and she said she'd write e.g. 'yay long'. It is very informal. The idea of 'yea' meaning 'like that' is a new one to both of us, and that spelling looks distinctly ancient for many people these days, Biblical knowledge being at an all-time low here.

Already addressed here, "I think Wentworth & Flexner, Dictionary of American Slang (1960). But perhaps the most interesting part of that entry is the source note accompanying it:     yea big, yea high 1 This big, or this high, accompanied with the spreading of the hands to indicate the size; very large or high, overwhelmingly large or tall. 2 Not very big or high. A sophisticated fad phrase since c1955."
